# Can't access the link to a local file with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, youtube

I am coding a youtube video downloader client with [a package from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl) so I can download the file to localhost but I can't access the link to it when i try to download it with the client

Here is [a link to the project](https://github.com/nazimboudeffa/youtube-dl-app) am coding on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

views/downloads/ 
locations doesn't exists. Create a directory inside views  folder

Comment: Thank you @raunik it was the first thing i thought it was the proble so i've created one on the server and also declared the `app.use(express.static('views/downloads'));` as you can see on the repo